# TranslateAnimation not working properly

Tags: android

Part of the code works without problems. However, in the second, the animation happens, but not in an appropriate way.

The views that should slide jumps to their respective positions (they are going to the correct positions, but not animating properly).

Does anyone have the solution to this undesired behavior?

GIF showing the problem[image]:

Code:

```
 public void animateCollapse(){

        final int count = getChildCount();
        final int tWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
        int widthSum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final RelativeLayout child = (RelativeLayout) getChildAt(i);
            widthSum += child.getWidth();
            child.clearAnimation();
        }
       if(!mTagLayout.isCollapsed()){

         //Removed piece of code, that works. 
        }
       } else{
           int currentPosX = 0;
           if(tWidth> widthSum) return;

           for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
               final View child = getChildAt(i);

               int lastpos = tWidth - child.getMeasuredWidth();

               float value =currentPosX - child.getX();
                       TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, value, 0, 0);
               anim.setDuration(1000);

               anim.setAnimationListener(new TranslateAnimation.AnimationListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

                   @Override
                   public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

                   @Override
                   public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
                   {
                   isAnimating= false;
                   }
               });

               anim.setFillAfter(true);
               child.startAnimation(anim);
               currentPosX += child.getMeasuredWidth();

               mTagLayout.setCollapsed(false);

           }
       }
```

@Edit
The views are not being destroyed and rebuilt during the animation

Comment: use ValueAnimator to  animate. You can call reverse to animate in reverse direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by using a reverse interpolator

```
 if (mTagLayout.isCollapsed()) {
      anim.setInterpolator(new ReverseInterpolator());
      mTagLayout.setCollapsed(false);
 } else {
      mTagLayout.setCollapsed(true);
 }


public class ReverseInterpolator implements Interpolator {
    @Override
    public float getInterpolation(float paramFloat) {
        return Math.abs(paramFloat - 1f);
    }
}
```